# Sometimes the program to hang and cannot perform any operation, and the code does not execute

Tags: dotnetbrowser

In the use of the win10 system, the CanLoadResource sometimes method causes the program to hang and cannot perform any operation, and the code does not execute. but it is normal to use in a win7 system. Why did this happen?

**Intercepting the Requests.**

```
Public Function CanLoadResource(resourceParams As ResourceParams) As Boolean Implements ResourceHandler.CanLoadResource
    If resourceParams.URL.Contains("gallery?") Then
        GM.theReadForm.Invoke(GM.theReadForm.MIBActionGaller, resourceParams.URL)
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

**GM.theReadForm.MIBActionGaller delegate registered a very simple method.**

```
Private Sub OnMIBActionGalleryCallback(ByVal urlstring As String)
    MessageBox.Show("OK")
End Sub
```

**Have you experienced something like me?**

**success log:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjanX.png)

**error log:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ7pK.png)

Comment: What version of DotNetBrowser did you use?

Comment: the version  is  1.14.3

Comment: It seems like a deadlock in the UI thread. Try to use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Comment: Thanks .Using BeginInvoke is really better than before.